# Intermediate fields

Tags: galois-theory

Let $K \subset F \subset L$ be finite-dimensional extensions of fields with $K \subset L$ Galois.
Show that the number of different intermediate fields that are $K$-isomorphic to $F$ is
$\frac{[F: K]}{\left|\operatorname{Aut}_{K}(F)\right|}$.

I tried to use that any k-isomorphism of fields F and F' is given by an element of the Galois group and vice versa
and fields are isomorphic iff their correponding groups in Gal(L/K) are conjugate.

Comment: What have you tried? What can you use?

Comment: I tried to use that any k-isomorphism of fields F and F' is given by an element of the Galois group and vice versa and fields are isomorphic iff their correponding groups in Gal(L/K) are conjugate.